# Javascript, eclipse and android

Tags: java, javascript, android, eclipse

I have learnt a bit of javascript from the website Codecademy and I have downloaded the software known as Eclipse. I know that javascript is a web dev language but i have also heard that it can be put into eclipse and can also be used to make android applications.I have looked around but couldnt find anything so can someone here tell me how to program in javascript in eclipse and also ,if i can, how to make android applications with it. Can someone link me to a website or youtube series or even tell me yourself on how to do this? Thanks :)

Comment: You could use Phonegap.

Comment: Btw, you dont have to use Eclipse for android.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a good start to set up Eclipse with Phonegap

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html

and this is the wiki

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Articles,_Tutorials,_Demos,_Books,_and_More